# Using the package Codebook in R and receiving errors saying that scale reliabilities cannot be computed

Tags: r, package, future, ufs

I have a labeled dataset in R, with defined scales:

```r
var_label(Data$Scale_1) <- 'Scale_1 Label'

 Data$Scale_1 <- Data |>
   select(all_of(Scale_1_Items)) |>
   aggregate_and_document_scale()
```

When I run the codebook function, which provides descriptives, histograms, missingness analyses, and scale diagnostics (using the User Friendly Science Package), and generates an excel data dictionary for my dataset:

```r
codebook(Data)
```

I receive this error: 'Warning: Reliability CIs could not be computed for Scale_1: plot.new has not been called yetWarning: Reliability could not be computed for Scale_1 Warning: plot.new has not been called yetWarning: UNRELIABLE VALUE: Future (‘’) unexpectedly generated random numbers without specifying argument 'seed'. There is a risk that those random numbers are not statistically sound and the overall results might be invalid. To fix this, specify 'seed=TRUE'. This ensures that proper, parallel-safe random numbers are produced via the L'Ecuyer-CMRG method. To disable this check, use 'seed=NULL', or set option 'future.rng.onMisuse' to "ignore".'

The function worked previously, and after I made additional changes to the code, to reflect needed adjustments to the labeling and scale variables, it no longer functions properly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.